# Short-cut key in VB.NET to take you to the end of the block

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When using VB.NET in Visual Studio 2010, is there any special key-combination to take you to the "other end" of a block?

In C# when your cursor is next to a brace (i.e. `{` or `}`) or brackets, you can click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> and it will move the cursor straight to the corresponding brace/bracket.

Is there such a thing in VB.NET so that if your cursor is on any part of an `If` statement (for example), you can be taken straight to the `End If`?

I realise that VB.NET makes life more difficult by having things like `If ... Then ... ElseIf ... Else ... End If` instead of braces, so I'm guessing the answer is probably "no".

(To clarify the last statement, what I mean is that in C# both the `if` and `else` can have specific braced areas, so going to the corresponding brace is a lot easier. In VB.NET if you did it on the If part, where would the IDE take you? The `Else`? The `End If`? Would it be expected to cycle through them?)

Comment: "I realise that VB.NET makes life more difficult by having things like If ... Then ... ElseIf ... Else ... End If instead of braces" -- care to substantiate that claim?

Comment: @roryap - what I mean is that in C# both the `if` and `else` can have specific braced areas, so going to the corresponding brace is a lot easier.  In VB.NET if you did it on the `If` part, where would the IDE take you?  The `Else`? The `End If`?  Would it be expected to cycle through them?